# Statistics Binomial Question

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, discrete-mathematics

A batch of $100$ iron rods consists of $25$ over-sized rods, $25$ Under-sized rods, $50$ rods of the desired length. if two rods are drawn at random without replacement. what is the probability of obtaining

1. two rods of the desired length.
2. one of the desired length.
3. None of the desired length.
4. two Undersized rods.

   I need help while using Binomial formula,  ${k \choose n}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$

Comment: @LeilaHatami And yet another useless edit to a 3+ years old question. Well done.

Comment: @Did Your Welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The binomial doesn't apply to sampling *without* replacement. Look up the hypergeometric distribution, it'll give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The first time you draw, there are $100$ possibilities.  Given the first draw, there are $99$ possibilities for the second draw, so this is not binomial.  Take this into account and the questions are easy:

1. First desired and second desired: $\dfrac{50}{100}\times \dfrac{49}{99}$
2. First desired and second undesired, or first undesired and second desired: $\dfrac{50}{100}\times \dfrac{50}{99}+ \dfrac{50}{100}\times \dfrac{50}{99}$
3. First undesired and second undesired: $\dfrac{50}{100}\times \dfrac{49}{99}$
4. First undersized and second undersized : $\dfrac{25}{100}\times \dfrac{24}{99}$

Note that the first three answers add up to $1$ since they disjointly cover all possibilities.